# Cannot install .run executable

Tags: software-installation

```
./mercurystandalone-3.3-linux-installer.run
```

nothing happened at all

double click the executable in file manager
it let me choose the default program to run

In `properties` I already checked the option `allow executing file as program`

The other command I tried:

```
uname -a
Linux ubuntu 3.8.0-34-generic #49~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 13 18:05:00 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

file ./mercurystandalone-3.3-linux-installer.run
./mercurystandalone-3.3-linux-installer.run: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, stripped

ldd mercurystandalone-3.3-linux-installer.run
    not a dynamic executable

sudo sh ./mercurystandalone-3.1-linux-installer.run
[sudo] password for xxx:
./mercurystandalone-3.1-linux-installer.run: 1: ./mercurystandalone-3.1-linux-installer.run: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

ls -l 
-rwxrwx--x 1 xxx xxx 142824167 Jan 28 10:58 mercurystandalone-3.1-linux-installer.run
```

Please help me install this program. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to install 3.3 or 3.1? Please edit your question to include the full error message at: "Syntax error: "(" unexpected..." I believe your sudo sh is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to execute a 32-bit executable on a 64-bit architecture. Get the matching 64-bit installer or install 32-bit libs.

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```